# Admin vs Domain account

Tags: permission, filevault, administrator

I created my iMac's account as a domain user without admin rights. My IT department then made my account an admin. Currently, every time I change or create files, or when I install softwares I am prompted to enter my admin user/password. Using `ls -l`, my files are created as "Domain Users" in the. Most files are 740.

My user account isn't enabled for FileVault use, so am not sure if that is the cause. I could change this under recovery mode, though would like to know before I go ahead with this.

Comment: On macOS, new files and folders inherit the group assignment from the folder they're created in. Where are these files being created, and what's the group assigned to that/those folder(s)?

Comment: I am creating these in my home directory. They're being assigned to "Domain User". I have a second computer where my files are created under "staff". It is most likely because that one wasn't created using the Domain's Active Directory

Comment: What group is the home directory assigned to?

Comment: there are 3 home directories. one is the IT department's who installed the OS and has filevault password. That is under "staff". I have two accounts one of which I am currently using. They're both assigned to Domain User. Both were give admin rights

Comment: So it sounds like whatever procedure they used to create your account set the home folder (and presumably the subfolders under it) to Domain Users, and because of that the things you create inside it inherit that assignment as well. Note that this has nothing at all to do with admin rights, FileVault, or even whether your account is a member of the Domain User group.